# Default settings for composition and item properties in print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Is it possible to make some default settings or save the settings for composition and item properties? 
Im adding a bunch of different maps to print composer. I want the same settings for every map f.eks the same position and size. When Im adding new maps, I have to change all the settings every time.

Comment: A print composer 'template' would accomplish this...

Comment: Are you adding multiple maps to the same print composer? Or do you create a new print composer each time?